# ImportError No module name drone_status

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am just starting out with learning ROS. I tried simulating the Ardrone, using the tum simulator on ROS Indigo and Gazebo2. Ref: https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator

I am trying to implement this code - https://github.com/amroygaol/AR_Drone_Example_code/blob/master/forward.py.
I followed through the instructions, however, I keep getting an error,

```
ImportError:No module named drone_status.
```

I can control the drone by directly publishing on the terminal, although, I cannot do it using the python script.

Can you please help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275593/importerror-no-module-name-drone_status/) by [tagomago](https://answers.ros.org/users/32583/tagomago/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's not being used. Try commenting out the offending line

```
from drone_status import DroneStatus
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0